# Programmatically Adding Data to a GtkTreeView/GtkListStore Created in Glade 3.12.1

Tags: c, gtk, gtk3, glade, gtktreeview

I've been teaching myself how to code in C and utilize GTK for writing applications in Linux, using Glade to design the UI before implementing it. I've been trying to utilize a GtkTreeView coupled with a GtkListStore to display data, but I seem to be running into issues. I can get my application to launch fine and it shows the window and dialog correctly, but I cannot figure out how to add rows of data to the List Store programmatically and have them appear in the Tree View; most tutorials I find seem to prefer to make the rows in Glade, or to design the whole interface through the code. With the code as it is I receive no errors when running the program, but I cannot see anything being added in GtkTreeView. I don't see any blank rows being added either.

By writing some code to forcibly generate an error, I can see that the signal for `postingButton` is being connected (I think) so that should be fine. I'm just missing something in my actual implementation of GtkTreeView. If anyone can help me out, I'd greatly appreciate it!

Edit: The GtkEntries that are present will be implemented later; I'm just trying to get data to show up at all.

C Code:

```
/* I'd give objects better names normally, no worries!
 * Just goofing around for now.*/

#include <gtk-3.0/gtk/gtk.h> // Needed for interface.
#include <gtk-3.0/gdk/gdk.h>
#include <glib-2.0/glib-object.h>

void on_mainWindow_destroy(GObject *object, gpointer user_data)
{
    gtk_main_quit();
}

void on_stupidButton_clicked(GtkButton *button, gpointer *user_data)
{
    gtk_dialog_run(GTK_DIALOG(user_data));
}

void on_postingButton_clicked(GtkButton *button, gpointer *user_data)
{
    GtkListStore *liststore1;
    GtkWidget *treeview1; // I've tried defining this as a GtkTreeView as well.
    GtkTreeIter iter;
    GtkBuilder *listStoreBuilder;

    listStoreBuilder = gtk_builder_new();
    gtk_builder_add_from_file(listStoreBuilder,
            "../testing_interface.glade", 0);

    treeview1 = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(listStoreBuilder,
            "treeview1")); // I'd change this to GTK_TREE_VIEW if the
                           // above is a GtkTreeView.
    liststore1 = GTK_LIST_STORE(
            gtk_tree_view_get_model((GtkTreeView *)treeview1));

    gtk_list_store_append(liststore1, &iter);
    gtk_list_store_set(liststore1, &iter, 0, "c", 1, "d", -1);

    gtk_builder_connect_signals(listStoreBuilder, 0);

    g_object_unref(G_OBJECT(listStoreBuilder));
    g_object_unref(G_OBJECT(liststore1));
}

void on_cancelButton_clicked(GtkButton *button, gpointer *user_data)
{
    gtk_widget_destroy((GtkWidget *)user_data);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    GtkBuilder *builder;
    GtkWidget *mainWindow, *dumbDialog;
    GtkButton *stupidButton;

    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

    builder = gtk_builder_new();
    gtk_builder_add_from_file(builder, "../testing_interface.glade",
            0);

    mainWindow = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "mainWindow"));
    stupidButton = GTK_BUTTON(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "stupidButton"));
    dumbDialog = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "dumbDialog"));

    gtk_builder_connect_signals(builder, 0);

    g_object_unref(G_OBJECT(builder));
    gtk_widget_show(mainWindow);
    gtk_main();

    return 0;
}
```

Glade File (testing_interface.glade):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<interface>
  <!-- interface-requires gtk+ 3.0 -->
  <object class="GtkDialog" id="dumbDialog">
    <property name="can_focus">False</property>
    <property name="border_width">5</property>
    <property name="type_hint">dialog</property>
    <child internal-child="vbox">
      <object class="GtkBox" id="dialog-vbox1">
        <property name="can_focus">False</property>
        <property name="orientation">vertical</property>
        <property name="spacing">2</property>
        <child internal-child="action_area">
          <object class="GtkButtonBox" id="dialog-action_area1">
            <property name="can_focus">False</property>
            <property name="layout_style">end</property>
            <child>
              <object class="GtkButton" id="postingButton">
                <property name="label" translatable="yes">Post</property>
                <property name="use_action_appearance">False</property>
                <property name="visible">True</property>
                <property name="can_focus">True</property>
                <property name="receives_default">True</property>
                <property name="use_action_appearance">False</property>
                <signal name="clicked" handler="on_postingButton_clicked" swapped="no"/>
              </object>
              <packing>
                <property name="expand">False</property>
                <property name="fill">True</property>
                <property name="position">0</property>
              </packing>
            </child>
            <child>
              <object class="GtkButton" id="cancelButton">
                <property name="label" translatable="yes">Cancel</property>
                <property name="use_action_appearance">False</property>
                <property name="visible">True</property>
                <property name="can_focus">True</property>
                <property name="receives_default">True</property>
                <property name="use_action_appearance">False</property>
                <signal name="clicked" handler="on_cancelButton_clicked" object="dumbDialog" swapped="no"/>
              </object>
              <packing>
                <property name="expand">False</property>
                <property name="fill">True</property>
                <property name="position">1</property>
              </packing>
            </child>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="expand">False</property>
            <property name="fill">True</property>
            <property name="pack_type">end</property>
            <property name="position">0</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkBox" id="box2">
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">False</property>
            <property name="orientation">vertical</property>
            <child>
              <object class="GtkEntry" id="entry1">
                <property name="visible">True</property>
                <property name="can_focus">True</property>
                <property name="invisible_char">●</property>
              </object>
              <packing>
                <property name="expand">False</property>
                <property name="fill">True</property>
                <property name="position">0</property>
              </packing>
            </child>
            <child>
              <object class="GtkEntry" id="entry2">
                <property name="visible">True</property>
                <property name="can_focus">True</property>
                <property name="invisible_char">●</property>
              </object>
              <packing>
                <property name="expand">False</property>
                <property name="fill">True</property>
                <property name="position">1</property>
              </packing>
            </child>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="expand">False</property>
            <property name="fill">True</property>
            <property name="position">1</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
      </object>
    </child>
    <action-widgets>
      <action-widget response="0">postingButton</action-widget>
      <action-widget response="0">cancelButton</action-widget>
    </action-widgets>
  </object>
  <object class="GtkListStore" id="liststore1">
    <columns>
      <!-- column-name Testing -->
      <column type="gchararray"/>
      <!-- column-name Testing1 -->
      <column type="gchararray"/>
    </columns>
  </object>
  <object class="GtkWindow" id="mainWindow">
    <property name="can_focus">False</property>
    <signal name="destroy" handler="on_mainWindow_destroy" swapped="no"/>
    <child>
      <object class="GtkBox" id="box1">
        <property name="visible">True</property>
        <property name="can_focus">False</property>
        <property name="orientation">vertical</property>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkTreeView" id="treeview1">
            <property name="height_request">183</property>
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">True</property>
            <property name="model">liststore1</property>
            <child internal-child="selection">
              <object class="GtkTreeSelection" id="treeview-selection1"/>
            </child>
            <child>
              <object class="GtkTreeViewColumn" id="testing1Col">
                <property name="title" translatable="yes">column</property>
                <child>
                  <object class="GtkCellRendererText" id="cellrenderertext1"/>
                  <attributes>
                    <attribute name="text">0</attribute>
                  </attributes>
                </child>
              </object>
            </child>
            <child>
              <object class="GtkTreeViewColumn" id="testing2Col">
                <property name="title" translatable="yes">column</property>
                <child>
                  <object class="GtkCellRendererText" id="cellrenderertext2"/>
                  <attributes>
                    <attribute name="text">1</attribute>
                  </attributes>
                </child>
              </object>
            </child>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="expand">False</property>
            <property name="fill">True</property>
            <property name="position">0</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkButton" id="stupidButton">
            <property name="label" translatable="yes">button</property>
            <property name="use_action_appearance">False</property>
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">True</property>
            <property name="receives_default">True</property>
            <property name="use_action_appearance">False</property>
            <signal name="clicked" handler="on_stupidButton_clicked" object="dumbDialog" swapped="no"/>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="expand">False</property>
            <property name="fill">True</property>
            <property name="position">1</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
      </object>
    </child>
  </object>
</interface>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code that appends rows to the tree view is basically okay, but several problems prevent it from working.

1. You are creating and populating a new builder on each entry to `on_postingButton_clicked`. This is obviously incorrect, because it means that you're creating a new tree and a new store on each click of the Post button. This is easily fixed by sending `treeview1` as `user_data` to the `on_postingButton_clicked` callback. You do that already in `dialog`, so I simply modified `<signal name="clicked" handler="on_postingButton_clicked" ...>` in your XML to also include `object="treeview1"`.
2. You are being too liberal with `g_object_unref`. `gtk_tree_view_get_model` doesn't increase the refcount of its model, so you shouldn't unref the liststore you get. Unrefing the builder in `main` is probably a bad idea if you want to pass it around and retrieve objects from it (and it's a singleton anyway).
3. You're supposed to `#include <gtk/gtk.h>`, without the intervening `gtk-3.0` directory. If your compilation fails without that, you are probably not setting up `pkg-flags` correctly.

Here is a modified version of your code that works for me. It requires XML to be modified as described above.

```
/* compile with:
   gcc -O2 -Wall glade-test.c $(pkg-config gtk+-3.0 gmodule-export-2.0 --cflags --libs) */

#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <gdk/gdk.h>
#include <glib-object.h>

void on_mainWindow_destroy(GObject *object, gpointer user_data)
{
    gtk_main_quit();
}

void on_stupidButton_clicked(GtkButton *button, gpointer *user_data)
{
    gtk_dialog_run(GTK_DIALOG(user_data));
}

void on_postingButton_clicked(GtkButton *button, gpointer *user_data)
{
    GtkTreeIter iter;
    GtkTreeView *treeview1 = GTK_TREE_VIEW(user_data);
    GtkListStore *liststore1 = GTK_LIST_STORE(gtk_tree_view_get_model(treeview1));

    gtk_list_store_append(liststore1, &iter);
    gtk_list_store_set(liststore1, &iter, 0, "c", 1, "d", -1);
}

void on_cancelButton_clicked(GtkButton *button, gpointer *user_data)
{
    gtk_widget_destroy((GtkWidget *)user_data);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    GtkBuilder *builder;

    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

    builder = gtk_builder_new();
    gtk_builder_add_from_file(builder, "testing_interface.glade", 0);
    gtk_builder_connect_signals(builder, 0);
    gtk_widget_show(GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "mainWindow")));
    g_object_unref(G_OBJECT(builder));
    gtk_main();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That works here, thanks @user4815162342! Obviously I still have a lot to learn, thank you for your help!